# Write a custom Kafka connect single message transform

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have configured a kafka connect Mongodb sink and I want to transform the message by implementing some custom logic.

Is Kafka connect  limited to in-built SMTs (or) is it possible to write a custom SMT. If not how can I achieve this? through streams?

Answer (score 6):

> Is Kafka connect limited to in-built SMTs

No, it is not. You can create your own and add them to your plugin path

> Transformations are compiled as JARs and are made available to Kafka Connect via the plugin.path specified in the Connect worker’s properties file. Once installed, the transforms can be configured in the connector properties.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples

Example repo https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-insert-uuid

Or my own https://github.com/OneCricketeer/schema-registry-transfer-smt

Comment: Instead of uuid, how can we load simple constant value in insrtusrid column in table

Comment: @SyedMohammedMehdi https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html