# How to set a document id in kafka elasticsearch sink connector as a combination of two fields?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a certain json where i need to set the document id as combination of two fields.

```
{
  "Event_start_time": "2021-05-16T08:27:21.164Z",
  "allbeat": {
    "heartbeat": {
      "pkt_loss_pct": 0,
      "type": "ping",
      "bu_id": 1,
      "minimum_rtt": 32.248,
      "jitter": 0.09999999999999788,
      "target_state": "Up",
      "average_rtt": 32.35,
      "maximum_rtt": 32.436,
      "tenant_id": 1,
      "target": "google.com",
      "port": 0
    }
  }
}
```

From the above document can we set a key with the combination of `Event_start_time` and `allbeat.heartbeat.target` using the available SMT's?

Comment: Last I checked, built in SMTs cannot combine fields. Doesn't mean you couldn't write your own

Comment: Didn't understand on how to deploy custom SMT from official documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604283/write-a-custom-kafka-connect-single-message-transform

Answer (score 0):

There is not an available Single Message Transform that I'm aware of that will do this. You could write your own, or you could use stream processing (e.g. Kafka Streams, ksqlDB) to do it