# Apache Kafka - Custom SMT

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a CDC process where I  receive the records and desserialize with Kafka Connector.

But are some garbage in the records, some come with Unicode Null:

Example:

```
{
"id": "1",
"account": "\u0000",
"phone": "123"
}
```

or

```
{
"id": "2",
"account": "123",
"phone": "\u0000"
}
```

Is there any SMT that I can "replaceAll" in all record, or that demands that I write my own Custom SMT, any reference of how can I do this writing a Custom SMT?
Thanks!

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604283/write-a-custom-kafka-connect-single-message-transform though as of now your question is off-topic because of "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"

Comment: There isn't a builtin one to do this. Any of the builtin ones typically work on one field, not all fields as well ... You can use ksql or Kafka Streams to filter these before using connect