# kafka connect transforms array json

Tags: couchbase, apache-kafka-connect

I set up kafka connector. I want to create new message from database record.
How do i get last element of nested list json?

how should transforms be?

```
    "transforms": "deserializaJson,t1",
    "transforms.ExtractLastElement.converter.type": "
    "transforms.deserializaJson.type": "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.transform.DeserializeJson",
    
    "transforms.t1.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
    "transforms.t2.renames": ??????
```

Database Json

```
{
  "name": "ali",
  "age": 30,
  "address": [
    {
      "city": "Istanbul",
      "country": "Turkey",
      "text": "address1"
    },
    {
      "street": "22 Rue du Grenier Saint-Lazare",
      "city": "Ankara",
      "country": "Turkey",
      "text": "address2"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected message

```
{
  "name": "ali",
  "selectedAddress": {
    "street": "22 Rue du Grenier Saint-Lazare",
    "city": "Ankara",
    "country": "Turkey",
    "text": "address2"
  }
}
```

i tried kafka connect Single Message Transforms

Comment: It's possible to [write a custom SMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604283/write-a-custom-kafka-connect-single-message-transform) if the built-in ones don't do what you want.