# Apache kafka transform de-flatten a flattened payload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup Apache Kafka source and sink connector for ServiceNow. The sink connector worked flawless where I was able to use below transformations to flatten a nested JSON payload to ServiceNow column names. [Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html)

```
"transforms": "FlattenSchema,RenameFields"
"transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
"transforms.flatten.delimiter": "."
```

Basically the transformation would flatten below JSON

```
"payload": {
    "prjtId": "123"
}
```

TO

```
payload.prjtId
```

Now I am trying out the source connector, that is to have Apache Kafka poll ServiceNow table for new records and stream them as Kafka message. The streaming messages works just fine but I am having trouble transforming the table record into expected nested JSON structure.

My ServiceNow table has below columns:

```
messageType
messageName
version
payload.projectId
payload.responseCode
```

When I retrieve this record as Kafka message using ServiceNow connector I would like to have it in below expected structure,

Expected result:

```
{

    "messageType": "InventoryRecordUpdate",
    "messageName": "Validated", 
    "version": "v1",
    "payload": {
        "projectId": "123456", 
        "responseCode" : "XXX"
    }
}
```

But when I try with below configs I get either result1 or result2 shown below:

With:

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
```

Result1: which basically throws in schema within the message and encapsulates the table columns under "payload":

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "u_messagetype"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "version"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "u_messagename"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "u_payload_projectid"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "u_payload_responsecode"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false
    },
    "payload": {
        "u_messagetype": "InventoryRecordUpdate",
        "u_version": "v2",
        "u_messagename": "Validated",
        "u_payload_projectid": "123456",
        "u_payload_responsecode": "200"
    }
}
```

And with below config,

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
```

Result2: Which excludes sending schema within the kafka message body and also removes the field called "payload" and sends the field as-is without nesting as shown below:

```
{
    "u_messagetype": "InventoryRecordUpdate",
    "u_version": "v2",
    "u_messagename": "Validated",
    "u_payload_projectid": "123456",
    "u_payload_responsecode": "200"
}
```

I did not find documentation that talks about de-flattening the keys 'u_payload_projectid' to a nested structure. Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There exists no transform to "de-flatten". The data you get is largely dependent on the connector itself. Seeing as the schema returned two top level string fields, and not a record/struct, there's nothing that can really be done from the Connect side without modifying source code of the connector

Therefore, you'll need to write some stream processor to detect fields with shared prefixes and re-map the data on your own

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it is not support natively within connector.  I will look into what my options are, but most likely I will use the flattened attributes as-is for now.

Comment: Writing your own custom transform is one option. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413052/2308683